# check server is bounced or not with time and date

Tags: linux, shell, unix

(if server shows time like 08:14 - then print server is up but if server shows date like Nov13 - print server is not up and send an alert message)

```
#!/bin/ksh

var1="$(ps -ef | grep 'abc' | grep -v 'grep' | tr -s " " | cut -d ' ' -f5)"
var2="$(date "+%H:%M")"
date="$(date "+%b%d")"

if [ "$var1" == "$var2" ]; then
   echo "Server has been bounced" > final.txt 
   echo " Success"
 elif expr "$var1" ">" "$var2" >/dev/null;  then
   echo "Server has been bounced" > final.txt
   echo " Success"  > final.txt
 elif [ "$var1" == "$date" ];  then
   echo "Server is not bounced" > final.txt 
   echo " Failure"  > final.txt
   mail -s " Failure,  Server is not bounced " final.abc@acb.com
fi
```

I tried to take the output of var1 with this following command of the server 5th column to check server is bounced or has been up or not

var1=`echo "ps -ef | grep 'abc' | grep -v 'grep' | tr -s " " | cut -d ' ' -f5"`

var1 output will be either date or time depends on if the server is bounced or not, if bounced shows time if not then shows date

var2=`echo "date "+%H:%M" "`

var2 output will be today's time.

Keeping in mind that time can be different also not on real time it is checking so if var1 output shows 03:14 and current time is 05:16 then also need to show server is up which i am trying with this

```
else if expr "$var1" ">" "$var2" >/dev/null
```

and then this command

date=`echo "date "+%b%d" "`

date output will be just a format like (Nov15) if the var1 output will be in the format of date variable then have to show server is not bounced and not up

but if var1 output will show time like 02:12 then have to compare with format of var2 and show server is bounced and up

stuck with the script in middle time script is working but date one is not giving the output

Comment: You want to see if a process is running since today, right? If `$var1` is a date (and not time), then the service is not bound, correct?

Comment: Yeah you are right ! Exactly if $var1 is date (not time) service is not bound and $var1 shows time (not date) service is bound. Please suggest the changes needed

Answer (score 0):

With the following you could get the amount of seconds since midnight:

```
$(($(date '+(%H*60+%M)*60+%S')))
```

Using `-o etimes` in `ps` you can get the amount of seconds since the process is running.
If you know the PID, you can do: `ps -p <pid> -o etimes=`. If you do not know the PID, you can use `grep` as you were already doing:

```
ps -e -o etimes,command|grep abc|awk '{print $1}'
```

Once you have both values, you can compare if the process running time is greater than amount of seconds since midnight.